# reading numbers from line in a file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I have this function process_input that basically gets a line of a file and prints the numbers of the line, if it has 2 numbers it prints those numbers and 0 else it prints the 3 numbers.

My problem is that for some reason its printing the lines repeatedly with a -1 token and I get why. Is there any error in my logic or something that im missing, is there a more efficient way of doing this? What I really want is to get the number from the file.

file:

```
4 4
6 4
5 10
10 3
4 8
1 2 5
2 3 6
2 4 2
3 4 1
```

My output:

```
4 4 - tokens: 2
6 4 0 - tokens: 2
5 10 0 - tokens: 2
10 3 0 - tokens: 2
4 8 0 - tokens: 2
1 2 5 - tokens: 3
1 2 5 - tokens: -1
2 3 6 - tokens: 3
2 3 6 - tokens: -1
2 4 2 - tokens: 3
2 4 2 - tokens: -1
3 4 1 - tokens: 3
3 4 1 - tokens: -1
3 4 1 - tokens: -1
```

Correct output:

```
4 4 - tokens: 2
6 4 0 - tokens: 2
5 10 0 - tokens: 2
10 3 0 - tokens: 2
4 8 0 - tokens: 2
1 2 5 - tokens: 3
2 3 6 - tokens: 3
2 4 2 - tokens: 3
3 4 1 - tokens: 3
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

void process_input(int** &graph, int &V, int &E)
{
    int n,k;
    char line[6];

    fgets(line,6,stdin);
    int tokens = sscanf(line, "%d %d", &n, &k);
    printf("%d %d - tokens: %d\n",n,k,tokens);

    int x,y,w = 0;
    while (fgets(line,6,stdin) != NULL)
    {
        tokens = sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &x,&y,&w);
        printf("%d %d %d - tokens: %d\n",x,y,w,tokens);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int V, E;
    int **graph;
    process_input(graph,V,E);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: C-style strings are null-terminated, which means `char line[6];` can store five meaningful characters before the null terminator. `fgets(s, size, stream)` reads at most one less than `size` characters from `stream`, and this includes the newline character, if any. So the line that contains `1 2 5` is read up to `5` and no newline character is read, because there is no place to store it. The next call to `fgets` reads just the newline character and no numbers. You may want to increase that `6` somewhat. How about using , um, I dunno, `1024` instead?

Comment: On a different note, you may want to use C++ facilities such as `std::string` and `iostreams` instead of the low-level C baggage, and not worry about these minute details.

Comment: Thanks man, i can't believe i was making such an ameuter mistake, i chose 6 because i thought it was small enough to fit any line of that file. By the way, im only using c++ because of the data structures, because i don't really know how to program in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that once you enter numbers in a loop you are not clearing your `stdin` buffer. You have mix of `C` and `C++` here.

in C++ you would do this:

```
while (fgets(line,6,stdin) != NULL)
{   
    tokens = sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &x,&y,&w);
    printf("%d %d %d - tokens: %d\n",x,y,w,tokens);
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.clear();
}
```

you have to include `iostream`. Using `C` way is well not perfect, but [here is SO post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)

Using hex output on closer inspection (this is for `C`, you are overwriting `\n`. Which makes `scanf` function fail that's why you are getting `-1` and why is it not clearing buffer by itself.

```
int n,k;
char line[7];

fgets(line,7,stdin);
int tokens = sscanf(line, "%d %d", &n, &k);
printf("%d %d - tokens: %d\n",n,k,tokens);

int x,y,w = 0;                                                                                                                                            
while (fgets(line,7,stdin) != NULL)
{
    tokens = sscanf(line, "%d %d %d\n", &x,&y,&w);
    printf("%d %d %d - tokens: %d\n",x,y,w,tokens);
}
```